# Getting SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when using proxy with python requests

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm trying to implement a proxy in python using the requests library but I keep getting the same error over and over again. This is my code:

```
proxies = {
        'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:24000',
        'https': 'https://127.0.0.1:24000',
    }
    resp = requests.get('https://api.myip.com', proxies=proxies)
    print(resp.text)
```

I am using Bright Data's proxy manager, and i suspect my implementation of the proxy is wrong. The error I'm getting is:

```
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.myip.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

I've tried solutions i found online like verify=false, which worked for this link but not for others I need to access, which is why I'm looking for a safer solution.

Comment: First, the https proxy setting should point to `http://...` and not `https://...` - at least if you use recent versions of requests. Then if you want it safer then you need to trust the specific CA which issued the certificate in question. It is unclear though what CA this is. And that verify=false does not work with other links might be simply because these are other problems which need to be handled differently - but without clear errors it is impossible to say how.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After i replaced the proxy setting it started working with this and other urls. Ill look into certificates and other errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a copy of the self-signed certificate and key you can modify the code as follow:

```py
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:24000',
    'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:24000',
}

certificate_path = os.path.join(CACERT_PATH, 'cacert.pem')
key_path = os.path.join(CACERT_KEY, 'cacert.key')

resp = requests.get('https://api.myip.com',
                    proxies=proxies,
                    cert=(certificate_path, key_path))
print(resp.text)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I don't understand a lot about ssl validation and certificates in general, so could you explain where i can get those files and what they are? Thanks in advance

Comment: Every OS provides a bundle of public CA (certificate authorities). When you connect to an https site that is validates but one of these entities, your browser tells you the site is secure (the same mechanisms is coded in `requests`). You got an error of "self signed certificate". Self-signed certificates are certificates signed by a CA that does not appears in the OS bundle. Most of the time it's an internal site signed by an internal CA. In this case you must ask the ops for the `cacert.pem` cert and `cacert.key` key. Otherwise you will not be able to connect to the site in a secure manner.

Comment: You can add `verify=False` in the requests call to bypass this issue, but you must understand the security implications of this choice.

Comment: Perfect to work behind enterprise proxy, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this problem behind a **corporate proxy**...

Then the problem you're seeing is that Requests library thinks there is a man in the middle attack going on. You can add a custom certificate through the **REQUEST_CA_BUNDLE** environment variable, and that'll tell requests to trust your proxy is not an attacker.

1. Ask your IT team for the certificate and they'll provide you with a pem, crt, or similar file. Unzip it.
2. Map the certificate to the **REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE** environment variable.

   `echo "export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<Path to Certificate>/ca-bundle.pem" >> $HOME/.bashrc`
3. Restart your terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc`

[Source: ZScaler](https://help.zscaler.com/zia/adding-custom-certificate-application-specific-trust-store). --> Has instructions for Windows & Mac... They also explain how to set this up for PIP.

Answer (score -2):

`verify=False` is a one way of doing it, but a better way to disable those warnings is to use this:

```
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

Comment: Downvoted for recommended to simply ignore certificate errors without showing the severe implications of this, i.e. that this disables the protection against active man in the middle attacks. Especially since the OP explicitly asked for *" which is why I'm looking for a safer solution"*

Comment: I believe safer meant something that will work in regards of any condition @SteffenUllrich :)